# The Word Biah In Mat 24:3 in George Howard's Hebrew Version of the Gospel of Matthew

Tags: linguistics, second-coming

I would like to know whether George Howard is still alive. He was the head of the Department of Religion in the University of Georgia and published the book Hebrew Gospel of Matthew, which contains his English translation of Shem Tob’s Hebrew text. (He is the same person who has been quoted many times in the publications of Jehovah's Witnesses in support of the usage of the Tetragrammaton in the Christian Greek Scriptures.)

George Howard’s translation uses the word biah (“coming”) in Matthew 24:3 where Greek versions have parousia. One source suggests that the word biah means “presence” and refers to an invisible presence of Christ. But its lexicon definitions correspond more to the idea of a coming rather than presence. Is the primary meaning of the word biah "coming," or is it "presence"?

(The website of the university where George Howard worked does not show his contact information. I have a question for George Howard and need to obtain his email address. Perhaps some of you may have his contact information.)

Regards,

Bernd

Comment: As it is your question is off-topic (asking for contact details). If you wish you can always append a short such request in parentheses. But you should edit your question to reflect the site's purpose: asking about a specific linguistic or textual issue (e.g. you could retain the "George Howard’s translation uses the word biah (“coming”) in Matthew 24:3 where Greek versions have parousia. One source suggests ... But its lexicon..." portion). I could help with editing it to be more on topic if you wish—welcome to the site!

Comment: παρουσία occurs four times in the Septuagint (in the Deuterocanon): Judith 10:18; 2 Maccabees 8:12, 15:21; and 3 Maccabees 3:17.  I don't have Hebrew versions of these, but it would be interesting to see which Hebrew words παρουσία translates in those cases.

Comment: @user33515 Judith had a Hebrew original, 2 and 3 Maccabees apparently were originally written in Greek in the Greek-speaking Jewish diaspora.